# Android App crashes when launching using Qt for Android

Tags: android, qt

I am trying this [example app](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/qt-creator-accelbubble-example.html) on qt's website. It builds without error and when I tried to run on a Samsung J7 with Android 8.1.0, it the white screen comes up and then the app crashes. In the Qt creator, this message shows as application output

```
E Zygote  : isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
E libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
E libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
W SELinux : SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-G610F_8.1.0_0008, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
I SELinux : SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=org.qtproject.example.androidTest4
I zygote  : Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
D MDO     : MDO if sIsMdo=false, sIsCheckMdo=false, uid = 10234
D Proxy   : mdoP is null: 10234
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
I QtCore  : Start
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4-wQpu1e5t-HXJTHLGN4W7gQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Network.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4-wQpu1e5t-HXJTHLGN4W7gQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4-wQpu1e5t-HXJTHLGN4W7gQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4-wQpu1e5t-HXJTHLGN4W7gQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Quick.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4-wQpu1e5t-HXJTHLGN4W7gQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Widgets.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4-wQpu1e5t-HXJTHLGN4W7gQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Svg.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4-wQpu1e5t-HXJTHLGN4W7gQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Sensors.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4-wQpu1e5t-HXJTHLGN4W7gQ==/lib/arm/libQt5Xml.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4-wQpu1e5t-HXJTHLGN4W7gQ==/lib/arm/libQt5QuickParticles.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4-wQpu1e5t-HXJTHLGN4W7gQ==/lib/arm/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4-wQpu1e5t-HXJTHLGN4W7gQ==/lib/arm/libQt5QuickControls2.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
I Qt      : qt start
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4/qt-reserved-files/plugins/sensors/libqtsensors_android.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
I Qt      : Sensors start
I zygote  : Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=27KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=27KB
I zygote  : Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
D OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
I zygote  : Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=59KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=60KB, data=59KB
I zygote  : Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I zygote  : Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=102KB
I zygote  : After code cache collection, code=109KB, data=78KB
D         : (null):0 ((null)): QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
D InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=56
D ViewRootImpl@74fba6a[QtActivity]: setView = DecorView@fbadb5b[QtActivity] TM=true MM=false
W Activity: AppLock checkAppLockState locked:false verifying:false pkgName = org.qtproject.example.androidTest4 isInMultiWindowMode:false showWhenLocked:false
D ViewRootImpl@74fba6a[QtActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
V Surface : sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
D ViewRootImpl@74fba6a[QtActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 3756800000} changed=true
I zygote  : android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
D libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : org.qtproject.example.androidTest4
D mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
D OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xe1f0ebc0, 0xdfec3808
D ViewRootImpl@74fba6a[QtActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
D ViewRootImpl@74fba6a[QtActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
V InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@aa71336 nm : org.qtproject.example.androidTest4 ic=null
D InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
I InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=65
D vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
V InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@2c1d237 nm : org.qtproject.example.androidTest4 ic=null
D InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/libqtquickcontrols2plugin.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtSensors/libdeclarative_sensors.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Window.2/libwindowplugin.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Templates.2/libqtquicktemplates2plugin.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : "/data/data/org.qtproject.example.androidTest4/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/Fusion/libqtquickcontrols2fusionstyleplugin.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W libandroidTest4.so: (null):0 ((null)): QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
W libandroidTest4.so: (null):0 ((null)): qrc:/main.qml:42 Cannot assign to non-existent property "footer"
08-23 11:53:51.290 11578 11648 W libandroidTest4.so:
D ViewRootImpl@74fba6a[QtActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
D InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=65
D OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0xe1f0ebc0, 0xdfec3800
D ViewRootImpl@74fba6a[QtActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true


"org.qtproject.example.androidTest4" died.
```

Since I have no prior experience in developing Android on Qt, I have no idea how to solve this issue. The setup in Qt for Android has the latest Android SDK, JRE inside the Android Studio folder and Android NDK version 17. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: `qrc:/main.qml:42 Cannot assign to non-existent property "footer"` i think that's the problem, but i don't understand why it shouldn't work. what Qt version are you using?